# AsyncTask onPostExecute UI Changes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

It is always the little things that stump me for hours.

I have an onPostExecute method from an AsyncTask class that looks like so:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {                       
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        showColumnCounts();
        dataDownloadCompleteToast();
    }
```

The toast works just fine. However, my showColumnCounts() method refuses to work. It works just fine on the main thread. I use it during onCreate() just not here. I thought the onPostExecute ran on the UI thread?

Here is my showColumnCounts() method if it is relevant.

```
public void showColumnCounts() {
    TextView totalView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalColumn2);
    TextView ignoredView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ignoredColumn2);
    TextView rView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rColumn2);

    Cursor c = myDB.getEmptyRColumn("");
    int count = c.getCount();
    if (count == 0) {
        c.close();
        return;
    }
    String unread = String.valueOf(count);
    String total = getTotalCount();
    int tTotal = Integer.parseInt(total);
    int r = tTotal - count;
    String read = String.valueOf(r);
    totalView.setText(total);
    ignoredView.setText(unread);
    rView.setText(read);
    c.close();
}
```

I've been fiddling with it for a while now assuming the answer should be obvious but I'm calling uncle. Can't figure it.

Edit***** 6/30

I THINK I've found my problem. In my background thread I am using a parse.com method "query.findInBackground" which I assume is starting a third thread? I'm trying to update this to "query.find" and I'm hoping that will fix.

Comment: move all your TextView declarations inside your onCreate (TextView totalView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalColumn2);)

Comment: Where is `showColumnCounts()` present? I mean in which class?

Comment: Atul O Holic my onCreate method is as follows...  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        openDB();
        Parse.initialize(this, "(my parse info", "my parse info");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spur_main);      
        showColumnCounts();
    }

Comment: Aniruddha my showColumnCounts() method is in my main class, SpurMain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should move all your TextView declarations inside your onCreate method
if you want to change or perform some UI operation, if you want to perform some non UI based operations while the thread is running then do that in doInBackground() method

Comment: Thanks Sharp, my TextView declarations are called in my onCreate() method through my showColumnCounts() method. This isn't the same thing?

Comment: @user986047 No you should initialize this line
    `TextView totalView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalColumn2);` in your onCreate() method.. because thats the method of android which is the starting point.. after that you can use   `totalView.setText(total);` in your showColumnCounts() method..

Answer (score 0):

You should move …setText(...) lines into
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    void run(){
    // UI stuff
    });

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell where is your `async class` located and the `showColumnCounts()` function located.

If they both where in different class then you should create a context to call the function from the async class.

Take this as example and try.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       new AsyncClass(this);
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void showColumnCounts() {
       TextView totalView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalColumn2);
       TextView ignoredView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ignoredColumn2);
       TextView rView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rColumn2); 

       Cursor c = myDB.getEmptyRColumn("");
       int count = c.getCount();
       if (count == 0) {
          c.close();
          return;
       }
       String unread = String.valueOf(count);
       String total = getTotalCount();
       int tTotal = Integer.parseInt(total);
       int r = tTotal - count;
       String read = String.valueOf(r);
       totalView.setText(total);
       ignoredView.setText(unread);
       rView.setText(read);
       c.close();
    }

    public class AsyncClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

         private Activity activity;
         public AsyncClass(Activity main_activity) {
            this.activity = main_activity;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String s) {                       
             super.onPostExecute(s);
             activity.showColumnCounts();
             dataDownloadCompleteToast();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: This almost worked, although I had to change activity.showColumnCounts() to activity.findViewById() etc. I tested with a hardcoded string and everything popped up on my UI just fine. However, in my showColumnCounts() method I'm making a call to my db and retrieving the total amount of rows. When I run the method my textview does not populate and it blocks my toast. Could it be my background operation? Gah

Comment: Could you post your full code(main class, async class, db class). so that i can let you know where is the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks achuthan I figured out the problem. One of my other methods was performing a long running operation on a background thread and so my initial code was working correctly but the background process was still running.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some UI change process in background running operation(ASYNC TASK),you write that codes in UI thread. Example:

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(
new Runnable() 
void run()
{

//UI changes
showColumnCounts();

});
```